# Formal proof of infimum of $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that **infimum** of $(0,1)$ is $0$.
Let $A=(0,1)=\{x:0<x<1\}$. clearly $0$ is lower bound of $A$. Let $a$ be a lower of $A$. Since $\frac{1}{2}\in A$, we have $a\leq \frac{1}{2}<1$. We claim that $0\geq a$. If not, $a>0$, then $a\in A$ and $\frac{a}{2}\in A$ then $a<\frac{a}{2}$. contradiction! Since $a$ is lower bound of $A$.(edited.)

---

But I didn't find contradiction.
I don't know where  I am wrong? I tried  a lot but i didn't prove it completely.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Just assume that the infinimum is $a>0$ and show that $\frac{a}{2}$ contradicts this assumption.

Comment: Please see my recent edit. Is it correct now?

Comment: "We claim that $0\leq a$." You mean to write $a\leq 0$.

Comment: Also, what you say about $\frac{1}{2}$ is correct and generalizes: "If $\epsilon>0$ then, since $\min\{\epsilon,\frac{1}{2}\}\in A$, we have $a \leq\epsilon$. So $a<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. So $a\leq 0$."

Comment: @halrakard: Is my proof correct now after editing $a\leq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to show:

Step 1: $0$ is a lower bound for $(0,1)$. Done; trivial as $x \in (0,1)$ implies $x > 0$ so $x \ge 0$ a fortiori.

Step 2: if $a$ is *any* other lower bound, $a \le 0$.

So suppose for a contradiction that $a$ is a lower bound for $(0,1)$ and $a>0$. Then $\frac{a}{2} \in (0,1)$ and $a \not \le \frac{a}{2}$ so contradiction as $a$ is **not** a lower bound for $(0,1)$ after all.

So $a \le 0$ from $\lnot (a >0)$.

Comment: I am feeling very stupid. Sometimes I didn't solve an easy problem. BTW thanks!

Comment: To be pedantic, we should take $b = \min(\frac12, \frac{a}{2}) \le \frac{a}{2} < a$ and also $b < 1$. $\frac a2$ could lie outside $(0,1)$ for large $a$.

Comment: :Yes. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

First, $0$ is a lower bound. Moreover, if $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$, then $x:=\frac{\varepsilon }{2}\in (0,1)$ and $$x\leq 0+\varepsilon,$$

The claim follow.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $0$ is the lower bound of $A=(0,1)$, as $a\gt 0 , \forall a \in A$

We should prove that , if $x $ is a lower bound of $A$ other than $0$ ,then, $x\lt 0 $.

If possible, let , there is lower bound $b$ of $A$ such that $b\gt 0 $ , then we choose a $\delta\gt 0 $ such that $b-\delta \gt 0 $, this is a contradiction to the fact that $b$ is lower bound of $A$, as $b-\delta \lt b $ and $b-\delta \in A=(0,1)$.

So, $0$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$.

Comment: I tried it but for large $\delta$ , $a=\delta$.

Comment: I didn't say arbitrary $\delta$,,,I say there is !!